Blazor - inputselect Retaining selectedIndex when options are Changed Dynamically
I have a number of inputselects that have options that are amended from other data on the screen. The selected item is never removed. However it seems that the list retains the selectedIndex and displays the item in that position, rather than the correct bound data. The options are updated correctly.
An example of the code is:
Source A
<select class="form-control form-select input" name="list-a" id="list-a" @bind:get="@(ItemA)" @bind:set="UpdateListA">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach (string value in GetListA())
    {
        <option value="@value">@value</option>
    }
</select>

Source B
<select class="form-control form-select input" name="list-b" id="list-b" @bind:get="@(ItemB)" @bind:set="UpdateListB">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach (string value in GetListB())
    {
        <option value="@value">@value</option>
    }
</select>

Source C
<select class="form-control form-select input" name="list-c" id="list-c" @bind:get="@(ItemC)" @bind:set="UpdateListC">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach (string value in GetListC())
    {
        <option value="@value">@value</option>
    }
</select>

Final D
<select class="form-control form-select input" name="list-d" id="list-d" @bind:get="@(ItemD)" @bind:set="UpdateListD">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach (string value in GetListD())
    {
        <option value="@value">@value</option>
    }
</select>

The required c# code to set up and manage the lists are below. These are a very simplified version of the actual business rules - I acknowledge that a more efficient way of writing these may exist but these just simulate the actual rules to demonstrate the problem.
private List<string> _listA = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
private List<string> _listB = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
private List<string> _listC = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
private List<string> _listD = [];

private string ItemA { get; set; } = "";

private string ItemB { get; set; } = "";

private string ItemC { get; set; } = "";

private string ItemD { get; set; } = "";

private List<string> GetListA () => [.. _listA.Order()];
private List<string> GetListB() => [.. _listB.Order()];
private List<string> GetListC() => [.. _listC.Order()];
private List<string> GetListD() => [.. _listD.Order()];


// ROUTINES USED TO SIMULATE BUSINESS RULES
// routines that populate final list with selected items from other list
// if a value is not selected in another list then the value is removed from the final list
// if the final list holds the value in source list then source selected value can't change

private void UpdateListA(string value)
{
    if ((ItemA == "") || (ItemA != ItemD))
    {
        if ((ItemA != ItemB) && (ItemA != ItemC))
            _listD.Remove(ItemA);

        if (!_listD.Contains(value))
            _listD.Add(value);

        ItemA = value;
    }
}

private void UpdateListB(string value)
{
    if ((ItemB == "") || (ItemB != ItemD))
    {
        if ((ItemB != ItemA) && (ItemB != ItemC))
            _listD.Remove(ItemB);

        if (!_listD.Contains(value))
            _listD.Add(value);

        ItemB = value;
    }
}

private void UpdateListC(string value)
{
    if ((ItemC == "") || (ItemC != ItemD))
    {
        if ((ItemC != ItemA) && (ItemC != ItemB))
            _listD.Remove(ItemC);

        if (!_listD.Contains(value))
            _listD.Add(value);

        ItemC = value;
    }
}


// Final List
private void UpdateListD(string value)
{
    ItemD = value;
}


Set the Source lists are set up as 'A', 'B' and 'C' and then Final list to 'B' (selectIndex = 3).
The problem comes when Source A is changed to 'D' as the Final list now shows 'C' (also selectIndex = 3) even though the data behind the scenes still holds the correct value or 'B'.

Can you come up with a [MRE] to demonstrate the problem?  It's difficult to understand fully from the text.

This post has now been updated with a reproduceable example.
